# MySQL trig math to calculate distance results in null

Tags: mysql

I'm running into a weird issue when calculating lat lng distance.
If I enter this query into mysql

```
SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(30.50492800)) * cos(radians(30.50492800)) * cos(radians(-90.49670600) - radians(-90.496706)) + sin(radians(30.50492800)) * sin(radians(30.50492800))))
```

it results in null. However, entering

```
SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(30.50492800)) * cos(radians(30.50492800)) * cos(radians(-90.49670600) - radians(-90.496706)) + sin(radians(30.50492800)) * sin(radians(30.50492700))))
```

or

```
SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(30.50492800)) * cos(radians(30.50492800)) * cos(radians(-90.49670600) - radians(-90.49670)) + sin(radians(30.50492800)) * sin(radians(30.50492800))))
```

gives a result.

Any reasons what would cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not weird at all,

none of the 3 expressions calculate the same thing.

---

**The differences**

`SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(30.50492800)) * cos(radians(30.50492800)) *` `cos(radians(-90.49670600) - radians(-90.496706)) + sin(radians(30.50492800)) *` `sin(radians(30.50492800))))`

`SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(30.50492800)) * cos(radians(30.50492800)) *` `cos(radians(-90.49670600) - radians(-90.496706)) + sin(radians(30.50492800)) *` `sin(radians(`**`30.50492700`**`))))`

`SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(30.50492800)) * cos(radians(30.50492800)) * cos(radians(-90.49670600) - radians(`**`-90.49670`**`)) + sin(radians(30.50492800)) * sin(radians(30.50492800))))`

---

**Evaluation**

- First expression

  1. `cos(radians(30.50492800))` is equal to `0.861585503968495`
  2. `cos(radians(30.50492800))` is equal to `0.861585503968495`
  3. `cos(radians(-90.49670600) - radians(-90.496706))` is equal to 1
  4. `sin(radians(30.50492800)) * sin(radians(30.50492800))` is equal to `0.257670419351355`
  5. so we evaluate `0.861585503968495 * 0.861585503968495 * 1 + 0.257670419351355` which give `1.000000000000000513393952565025`
  6. `acos(1.000000000000000513393952565025)` return null.
- Second expression

  1. `cos(radians(30.50492800))` is equal to `0.861585503968495`
  2. `cos(radians(30.50492800))` is equal to `0.861585503968495`
  3. `cos(radians(-90.49670600) - radians(-90.496706))` is equal to 1
  4. `sin(radians(30.50492800)) * sin(radians(30.50492700))` is equal to `0.257670411718131`
  5. so we evaluate `0.861585503968495 * 0.861585503968495 * 1 + 0.257670411718131` which equal `0.999999992366776513393952565025`
  6. `acos(0.999999992366776513393952565025)` = `0.000123557464423953`
  7. `3959 * 0.000123557464423953` = `0.489164001654431`
- Third expression

  1. `cos(radians(30.50492800))` is equal to `0.861585503968495`
  2. `cos(radians(30.50492800))` is equal to `0.861585503968495`
  3. `cos(radians(-90.49670600) - radians(-90.49670))` is equal to `0.999999999999995`
  4. `sin(radians(30.50492800)) * sin(radians(30.50492800))` is equal to `0.257670419351355`
  5. So we evaluate `0.861585503968495 * 0.861585503968495 * 0.999999999999995 + 0.257670419351355` which equal `0.999999999999996801746049321797`
  6. `acos(0.999999999999996801746049321797)` equal `8.16170211889098e-08`
  7. Multiply by `3959` and we get `0.000323121786886894`

---

**Why does acos(1.000000000000000513393952565025) return null ?**

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_acos),

> Returns the arc cosine of X, that is, the value whose cosine is X.
>   Returns NULL if X is not in the range -1 to 1.

As you can see, `1.000000000000000513393952565025` is higher then 1.

For the two other expressions that does not give null, the given parameter to `acos` are

- 0.999999992366776513393952565025
- 0.000323121786886894

Which are both in the range `[-1, 1]` so we get no null.

Comment: Thanks, I added in a range check inside of acos to set it to 1 or -1 if it was outside of that range.